# Simultaneously scrolling two divs in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

*Edit 3:* I think this is the closest I've been.. Since this is react, I am adding an event listener in the constructors:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const self = this;
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('scroll-content')).forEach((element) => {
      element.addEventListener('scroll',
        () => self.scrollDivsTogether(element.parentElement.parentElement.id));
    });
  }
```

And then my function is just like this:

```
scrollDivsTogether(id) {
    const opt = $('#options-column>table>tbody.scroll-content');
    const cont = $('#options-contents>table>tbody.scroll-content');

    if (cont.scrollTop() !== opt.scrollTop()) {
      if (id === 'options-column') {
        cont.scrollTop(opt.scrollTop());
      } else {
        opt.scrollTop(cont.scrollTop());
      }
    }
  }
```

It still triggers on both events, but a bit less. I don't know how to make this into a fiddle though... Perhaps I need to add a delay somewhere?

Also, my HTML looks sort of like this:

```
<div id='table-container'>
  <div id='options-column'>
    <table>
      <thead class='fixed-header'>
        <tr>
          <th>Heading</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class='scroll-content'>
        <tr>
          <td>h1</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- more tr's here -->
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id='options-contents'>
    <table>
      <thead class='fixed-header'>
        <tr>
          <th>A1</th>
          <th>A2</th>
          <th>A3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class='scroll-content'>
        <tr>
          <td>a1</td>
          <td>a2</td>
          <td>a3</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- more tr's here -->
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Edit 2:* 
I did make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tv8bkyc/5/), but it's not working with the "onscroll" event and I'm not sure how to do pure JS calls in React... Anyway, a working jquery one is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1tv8bkyc/6/), but I wonder if this is lagging because I am using `onscroll`?

*Edit 1:* the function that I think conforms to what @Lokman Hakim suggested, but is very choppy on my end.

```
scrollDivsTogether() {
  $('.scroll-content').on('scroll', (e) => {
    const ele = $(e.currentTarget);
    const top = ele.scrollTop();

    if (ele.parent().parent().attr('id') === 'options-contents') {
      // already scrolled contents, scroll only the column
      $('#options-column>table>tbody.scroll-content').scrollTop(top);

      // already scrolled column, scroll only the contents
    } else {
      $('#options-contents>table>tbody.scroll-content').scrollTop(top);
    }
  });
}
```

---

*Original:*

I currently have this code which works fairly well:

HTML (actually jsx file):

```
    <div id='table-container' onScroll={this.scrollDivsTogether}>
      <div id='options-column'>
        <table>
          <BuildHeader ... /> <!-- consists of a thead of class fixed-header--> 
          <BuildRows ... /><!-- consists of a thead of class scroll-content --> 
        </table>
      </div>

      <div id='options-contents'>
        <table>
          <BuildHeader ... /> <!-- consists of a thead of class fixed-header--> 
          <BuildRows ... /><!-- consists of a tbody of class scroll-content --> 
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#table-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    &:hover {
        overflow-x: overlay;
    }
}
.fixed-header tr {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.scroll-content {
    display: block;
    overflow: overlay;
    width: 100%;
}
#options-column {
    border: solid 1px $lightBlue;
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 240px;
    min-width: 240px;
    width: 240px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}
#options-contents {
    overflow: visible;
    margin-left: 240px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Javascript:

```
scrollDivsTogether() {
  const opt = $('#options-column>table>tbody.scroll-content');
  const cont = $('#options-contents>table>tbody.scroll-content');

  opt.on('scroll', function () {
    cont.scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
  });

  cont.on('scroll', function () {
    opt.scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
  });
```

Now, that code works reasonably we, but it's sometimes laggy and it sometimes gets stuck like this (the lines are supposed to align):

[image: the lines are supposed to align]

It's also quite bothering me that triggering scrolltop in one callback triggers scrolltop in the other callback, when I should be able to block the other or something. I've tried everything I could think of though... Help?

This is [my site](https://ideal-engine.herokuapp.com/SelectTable) if you want to see it "in action" (select a table from the list).

Comment: it would be better if you can provide working jsfiddle which match with your case. Because `JQuery` that you provides contain `tbody.scroll-content`, while I dont see it inside your HTML

Comment: Don't put on scroll inside on scroll, each time you scroll, new event will be created. You'll end up creating huge load of unnecessary event and it will slow down your page.

Comment: Yanaro, that was the problem, how do I get around it?

Comment: Added a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1tv8bkyc/6/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1tv8bkyc/8/ this works just fine. The setTimeout is so that when you're scrolling an element, the other element won't fire scroll event. For the above question, make sure to run "this.scrollDivsTogether" method only once, maybe inside componentDidMount if you're using react.

Comment: If you want the answer karma, you should make this an answer, it worked completely! @Yanaro

Comment: I have updated my answer with the content of the comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about trying this? Might not be optimal though.
Here is a snippet of the code https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/1381/2/Scrolling-two-divs-at-the-same-time
https://jsfiddle.net/1tv8bkyc/8/

```
var optTimeout, contTimeout;

opt.on('scroll', function () {
  if(contTimeout) return;
  if(optTimeout) clearTimeout(optTimeout);
  optTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
     if(optTimeout) {
       clearTimeout(optTimeout);
       optTimeout = null;
     }
    }, 50);
  cont.scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});

cont.on('scroll', function () {
  if(optTimeout) return;
  if(contTimeout) clearTimeout(contTimeout);
  contTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
     if(contTimeout) {
       clearTimeout(contTimeout);
       contTimeout = null;
     }
  }, 50);
  opt.scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

The setTimeout is so that when you're scrolling an element, the other element won't fire scroll event. For the above question, make sure to run "this.scrollDivsTogether" method only once, maybe inside componentDidMount if you're using react

Comment: This seems to still get called on both events

Answer (score 1):

try take a look from this link

https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/332/Scrolling-two-divs-at-the-same-time

Comment: I see what you're doing there, but mine just ends up being choppier... For the record, I'll update the question with what I have (cause the markup is better there)